# Reorder label ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following function:

```
ggplot(parte2, aes(IDENTIFICADOR,MEM_A)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 5))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100000, 2000))
```

but this give me a graphic without order the level x, and i want to order it due to the value that takes de IDENTIFICADOR in the MEM_A.

I use the following function:

```
ggplot(parte2, aes(as.numeric(reorder(IDENTIFICADOR,MEM_A)),MEM_A)) + 
  geom_point()  + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100000, 2000))
```

the plot is order but the index in the axes x it isnt is correct.

```
INPUT_1<-parte2[,2]
INPUT_2<-parte2[,3]
CPU_A<-parte2[,4]
MEM_A<-parte2[,5]
CPU_B<-parte2[,6]
MEM_B<-parte2[,7]

ggplot(parte2, aes(fct_reorder(IDENTIFICADOR, MEM_A, min),MEM_A)) + 
  geom_point()+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100000, 2000))
```

Comment: The function you're probably looking for is `fct_reorder`.  The answers to this previous question should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799074/how-to-reorder-a-factor-in-a-dataframe-with-fct-reorder

Comment: I use it but still doesnt work. ;(

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? You can use `dput` to get a pasteable version of your data.

Comment: when i use scale_x_continuous i lost the order

Comment: Because you've used the fct_reorder, your X aesthetic is a factor now and therefore a discrete variable. Use scale_x_discrete instead.

Comment: I edit with my code, i need to define the ticks of the x axis